# extend a base class method by specifying default parameters

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, overriding, function-pointers

I'd like to define a method in the base class and then specify some default parameters to override it in the derived class. The parameter in question is a function pointer and the function it points to is itself a base class function I override in the derived class. If I just specify the parameter it asks me for an other definition, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid adding further definitions.

```
class mover: public piece
{
public:
    mover(const char t);
    ~mover() { };
    virtual bool life_status(piece victim) = 0;
    void move(piece victim, size_t newr, size_t newc, bool(mover::*life_status)(piece));
};
class diplomat : public mover {
public:
    diplomat(const char t);
    ~diplomat() { };
    bool life_status(piece victim) { return victim.status(); }
    void move(piece victim, size_t newr, size_t newc, bool(mover::* life_status)(piece)= mover::life_status);
};
class necromobile : public mover {
public:
    necromobile(const char t);
    ~necromobile() { };
    bool life_status(piece victim) { return !victim.status(); }
    void move(piece victim, size_t newr, size_t newc, bool(mover::*life_status)(piece)= mover::life_status);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add definition, but you can just forward to base class:

```
void diplomat::move(piece victim,
                   size_t newr,
                   size_t newc,
                   bool(mover::* life_status)(piece)/*= mover::life_status*/)
{
    mover::move(victim, newr, newc, life_status);
}
```

Notice though that it is dangerous to default with other value than base, as default value would depend of static_type, not dynamic type, which might be confusing:

```
diplomat d;
mover& m = d;

d.move(victim, newr, newc); // OK, default argument mover::life_status
m.move(victim, newr, newc); // ERROR, mover doesn't have default argument
```

Comment: I'll move my default parameters in the base class virtual function then. Thank you very much! That could have been an headache bug.